# Accessing methods inside Module Class that extends ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, module, rubygems

So I am writing a gem that has multiple lib files that each contain classes of the same module like so:

**Main "loader" lib**

```
#lib/jobhandler.rb

require 'jobhandler/job'

module JobHandler
end
```

**Another Class of same module in another file**

```
#lib/jobhandler/job.rb

module JobHandler
  class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.class_thingy
      return "I am a class method"
    end

    def instance_thingy
      return "I am an instance method of a class inside a module that extends AR"
    end
  end
end
```

**Problem**

```
# These work fine....
Autocrat::Job.new # <Autocrat::Job:0x7fd9b017a138>
Autocrat::Job     # Autocrat::Job(id: integer....) < ActiveRecord::Base

#But this doesn't
Autocrat::Job.class_thingy # NoMethodError: undefined method `class_thingy'
Autocrat::Job.new.instance_thingy # NoMethodError: undefined method `instance_thingy'

#it doesn't even see the methods
Autocrat::Job.methods - ActiveRecord::Base.methods # []
```

The problem is that I can't access or invoke the class or instance methods for my Job class. I can instantiate Job just fine, it just doesn't seem to know that the methods exist.

Any ideas?

Comment: A module can't extend a class as it's written above.  Secondly, the string is not terminated properly in "I am a class method.  Can you please upload an example that you were successful in loading through irb

Comment: I edited the code above. How would you go about making the methods accessible to the Job class

Comment: Works for me:     [3] pry(main)> JobHandler::Job.new.instance_method
=> "I am an instance method of a class inside a module that extends AR"

Comment: For instance method : JobHandler::Job.new.instance_method  For class_method : JobHandler::Job.class_method

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe I should have given more info. Editing the above to reflect my setup.

Comment: Can you post your ActiveRecord model class? For example, where you define Autocrat?